# A real number lies in all of the intervals $I_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $I_n=[a_n, b_n]$ is a sequence of non-empty closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the intervals become smaller and smaller as $n$ goes to infinity. Prove that there exists a real number $x$ which lies in all of the intervals $I_n$.

I let $A= \{a_n\}, B=\{b_n\}$, based on condition I say $a_n$ is less than or equal to $b_n$ for all $n$. It follows that $\sup(A)$ is less than or equal to $\inf(B)$. But what is the next step to prove it?

Comment: Since $\sup(A) \le \inf(B)$, $\sup(A)\le b_n$ for all $n$ and $\sup(A)\ge a_n$ so it is contained in each set.

Answer (score 1):

However,
nowhere is it stated that
the intervals are nested!!!

The first two intervals
could be
$[0, 1]$ and
$[2, 2.5]$.